# Align three objects in HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm new to both HTML and CSS. As a course module I have to align the three following cat pictures as stated below. Yet, I do have trouble to get them in the proper positioning. The pictures are in line right now but the second picture has to be a little "underneath" a horizontal line.

Can someone give me a hint how to do this? Below you find the outcome I'm aiming for as well as my code.

[image]

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
}

#cat1 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat3 {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box wrap">
    <div id="cat1"><img src="images/kitty1_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
    <div id="cat2"><img src="images/kitty3_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
    <div id="cat3"><img src="images/kitty2_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS Grid, this layout becomes straightforward and maintainable:

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#cat2 {
  grid-row-start: 2;
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

#cat3 {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div id="cat1">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/120/120" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="cat2">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/120/120" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="cat3">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/120/120" alt="" />
  </div>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `flex` and then `align` and center `images`

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

  

#cat1 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
 float:right;
}

#cat3 {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  top: 25%;
  left: 45%;

}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box wrap">
    <div id="cat1"><img src="images/kitty1_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
    <div id="cat2"><img src="images/kitty3_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
    <div id="cat3"><img src="images/kitty2_150x150.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `justify-content:space-between;` for the box-wrap class, to add space between the the children.

Also u named the class wrongly. Change **"box wrap"** to **"box-wrap"**

For getting the second image underneath, there are multiple answers depending on what type layout u want.

I have simply put the middle image on next line and centered it by wrapping it in a `div`

Another way is to make the **position** of center image **absolute**.
Using this method the dom structure will not change.

```css
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#cat1 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat3 {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div id="cat1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>

    <div id="cat3"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="text-center">

    <div id="cat2"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Using Grid

```css
*{
box-sizing:border-box;
}
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.box-wrap {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-rows: 150px 150px;
}

#cat1 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
}

#cat2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  grid-column-start: 2;
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

#cat3 {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
  <title>Cats</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div id="cat1" class="text-center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div id="cat2" class="text-center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
    <div id="cat3" class="text-center"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: can we use `display: grid` to achieve this layout. just asking for my knowledge. if you can make this with it, then surely it will be the best answer.

Comment: superb, thats what i was looking for. take my upvote.. cheers

Comment: @dennisN86 you should set this as best answer and accept it

Answer (score 0):

hi you can try below code : https://jsfiddle.net/fh86hejs/

```
body {
  background-color: white;
}

.box-wrap {
  display: flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
}

#cat1 {
  border: 3px solid blue;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat2 {
  border: 3px solid grey;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

#cat3 {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.text-center{
text-align:center;
}
```

HTML code as below

```
    <html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
    <title>Cats</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="box-wrap">
    <div id="cat1"><img src="https://imaginicupisici.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Pisicuta-mica-de-tot.jpg">
      </div>

    <div id="cat3"><img src="https://imaginicupisici.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Pisicuta-mica-de-tot.jpg">
      </div>
  </div>
   <div class="text-center">

    <div id="cat2"><img src="https://imaginicupisici.ro/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/Pisicuta-mica-de-tot.jpg">
      </div>

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```